# Dynamically Populate Gravity Forms Based on Start Date

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

In Gravity Forms plugin I've tried to dynamically populate End Date and End Time based on the Start Date and Start Time values but no luck.

This is the code I used to dynamically populate End Date:

```
<?php
add_filter("gform_field_value_date", "populate_date");
function populate_date($value){
return date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+0 days'));
}
?>
```

This actually works but it adds '+0 days' to the submission date and not to the 'Start Date' value.

Same goes with time. I want to have the ‘End Time’ field auto-populated, i.e. End Time = Start Time. And I want to add “+1 hour” to the ‘Start Time’ and thus get ‘End Time’.

Any suggestions?
Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution for the Date bit:

http://gravitywiz.com/populate-dates-gravity-form-fields/

Your use case would look something like this:

```
new GW_Populate_Date( array(
    'form_id' => 1,         // update to your form ID
    'target_field_id' => 1, // update to the ID of the 'End Date' field
    'source_field_id' => 2  // update to the ID of the 'Start Date' field
) );
```

What kind of Time field configuration are you using? Got a link to your form?